# Cutoff value for predict function in R

Tags: r, predictive-models, discriminant-analysis, confusion-matrix

when I use this code to generate the confusion matrix, I'm not really sure what is used as the cutoff value. Is it by default 0.5, or something else?

```r
qda.fit = qda(diabetes ~ ., data = train)
qda.pred = predict(qda.fit, newdata = test)$class
qda.prob = predict(qda.fit, newdata = test)$posterior
table(qda.pred, test$diabetes)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`?predict.qda`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-53/topics/predict.qda) tells us that the `$class` component is a maximum a posteriori (MAP) classification, i.e., the class whose posterior likelihood is maximal among all classes. (Since `qda` allows for *multi-class* classification, it does not necessarily make sense to discuss thresholds.)

Comment: But how does it classify without specifying a threshold then? And how do I specify a threshold if I want to do so?

Comment: Apparently (I am no expert in `qda`), it uses a Bayesian approach, specifying prior class membership probabilities, updating them with data, and obtaining posterior class membership probabilities. Then it simply looks which class has the highest posterior membership probability. There is no score involved that is compared to a threshold.